# After adding mobile detect in varnish{default.vcl}, varnish not starting

Tags: mobile, device, varnish

I had a basic default.vcl for my website and it was working.

I added the below code to detect and serve different theme for user if coming form pc or mobile. After adding the below code to detect the mobile device, varnish is not starting.

How do I solve this so varnish detects the mobile device and so the mobile theme is served in same url if visited from mobile,table

```
    /*
    *
    * First, set up a backend to answer the request if there's not a cache hit.
    *
    */
    backend default {

        # Set a host.
        .host = "xx.xx.xx.xx";

        # Set a port. 80 is normal Web traffic.
        .port = "xxxx";
    }
    /*
    *
    * Next, configure the "receive" subroutine.
    *
    */
    acl admin_ip {
       "xx.xx.xx.xx";
    }
    include "devicedetect.vcl";
    sub vcl_recv {
            call devicedetect;
            if (req.request == "PURGE") {
            if (!client.ip ~ admin_ip) {
                error 405 "You can't do this, muggle!";
            }
                return(lookup);
       }
    if (!req.backend.healthy) {
        unset req.http.Cookie;
      }
    set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;

        # Use the backend we set up above to answer the request if it's not cached.
        #set req.backend = default;

        if (req.url ~ "^/user/login" ||
            req.url ~ "^/oc-admin" ||
            req.url ~ "^/item/new" ||
            req.request == "POST")
        {
            return (pass);
        }
        if (req.url ~ "(?i)\.(pdf|asc|dat|txt|doc|xls|ppt|tgz|csv|png|gif|jpeg|jpg|ico|swf|css|js)(\?.*)?$") {
        unset req.http.Cookie;
        unset req.http.Cache-Control;
        unset req.http.Max-Age;
        unset req.http.Pragma;
        unset req.http.Cookie;
      }
       if(req.http.Cookie) {
         if (req.http.Cookie !~ "(sessionid|XXXid)" ) {
           remove req.http.Cookie;
         }
      }
        # Pass the request along to lookup to see if it's in the cache.
        return(lookup);
    }
    /*
    *
    * Next, let's set up the subroutine to deal with cache misses.
    *
    */
    sub vcl_miss {

        # We're not doing anything fancy. Just pass the request along to the
        # subroutine which will fetch something from the backend.
        return(fetch);
    }
    /*
    *
    * Now, let's set up a subroutine to deal with cache hits.
    *
    */
    sub vcl_hit {

        # Again, nothing fancy. Just pass the request along to the subroutine
        # which will deliver a result from the cache.
        return(deliver);
    }
    /*
    *
    * This is the subroutine which will fetch a response from the backend.
    * It's pretty fancy because this is where the basic logic for caching is set.
    *
    */
    sub vcl_fetch {

    if (req.http.X-UA-Device) {
            if (!beresp.http.Vary) { # no Vary at all
                set beresp.http.Vary = "X-UA-Device";
            } elseif (beresp.http.Vary !~ "X-UA-Device") { # add to existing Vary
                set beresp.http.Vary = beresp.http.Vary + ", X-UA-Device";
            }
        }
       #unset beresp.http.expires; # for cloudfront since it prefers cache-control
                                  # header over expires

       if (req.url ~ "(?i)\.(pdf|asc|dat|txt|doc|xls|ppt|tgz|csv|png|gif|jpeg|jpg|ico|swf|css|js)(\?.*)?$") {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
       }
       if (req.http.Content-Type ~ "(image|audio|video|pdf|flash)") {
            set beresp.do_gzip = false;
       }
       if (req.http.Content-Type ~ "text") {
            set beresp.do_gzip = true;
       }
      # Varnish determined the object was not cacheable
        if (beresp.ttl  0) {
        set resp.http.X-Varnish-Cache = "HIT";
      }
      else {
        set resp.http.X-Varnish-Cache = "MISS";
      }

      return (deliver);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to start varnish with

```
varnishd -F -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl
```

so you can see all messages/errors. btw: you include a `devicedetect.vcl`. without this file, it's hard to say what's going wrong ;)

Comment: after using above mention command it showed me like error in <code> # Varnish determined the object was not cacheable
        if (beresp.ttl  0) {
        set resp.http.X-Varnish-Cache = "HIT";
      }
      else {
        set resp.http.X-Varnish-Cache = "MISS";
      }</code>  so i change this (beresp.ttl  0 as (beresp.ttl  >=0s) and than varnish started but it is not cahing anything

Comment: the device detect vcl is [link](https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-devicedetect/blob/master/devicedetect.vcl)